# CodeIgniter, jQuery load and strange Google indexing of my content

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, seo, indexing

I have a strange problem with the Google indexing of my website. It is a problem with all search engines, but I will use Google as example. (the website is in Bulgarian)

The website is for cooking recipes. It is build using CodeIgniter and it uses the jQuery load function to load the comments for the recipes. The jQuery load calls a controller function which is not directly accessible via URL request, but only if the request is ajax.

If you try to access the get comments function directly (not ajax) you are redirected to the recipe corresponding to the uri segments (or homepage if nothing was found).

The problem is, that Google index only my ajax requests but not the actual page of the recipe.

Below I'm placing the code and links to the problems.

The domain is http://www.gotvachnicata.com/ and we can grab for instance the following recipe: http://www.gotvachnicata.com/potrebiteli/gotvachnicata/recepta/domashna-pica-sas-salam-i-lyuti-chushki

we have the ajax request that loads the comment executed at the following way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.recipe-comments').load('http://www.gotvachnicata.com/process/get_recipe_comments/24');
});
```

The last segment is the ID of the recipe. If you request this controller function through ajax you get the comments for the recipe with this ID, if you try to direct access it you are redirected to the recipe with this ID. This is done with the following code.

```
if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
         //Load the comments
    } else {
         //Redirect to the recipe    
}
```

I have my sitemap submitted to Google. 
You can see it here: http://www.gotvachnicata.com/sitemaps/sitemap_recipes.xml

I'm also using Structured Data (http://schema.org/) if this makes any difference.

And at the end the actual problem - When I search Google for my recipe (link for the search http://bit.ly/XhNk3K) I receive the following link displayed in the search results

http://www.gotvachnicata.com/process/get_recipe_comments/24

instead of

http://www.gotvachnicata.com/potrebiteli/gotvachnicata/recepta/domashna-pica-sas-salam-i-lyuti-chushki

And this apply for all recipes on the website. It looks like Google index the ajax request instead of the actual page.

I really have no idea of why it does this and what I need to change to fix it. As for me the SEO is really important for this website I would like to have SEO friendly URLs indexed in Google.

Comment: I get the response: http://www.gotvachnicata.com/potrebiteli/gotvachnicata/recepta/domashna-pica-sas-salam-i-lyuti-chushki from that search, but you could add no-follow to those links pointing to /process/get_recipe_comments/24

Comment: @Iesus Sonesson can you confirm, that in your Google search the link displayed in the results is not this one? http://img839.imageshack.us/img839/4025/gotvachnicatasearch.jpg This is what I'm talking about. After you click on this link you are redirected to the recipe, but this is not intended and not what I want. Also I cannot add no-follow to the ajax request as far as I know.

Comment: Hi Alex, Yes for me the link that i posted was the one that was linked from google in your search however the results on google are varying from your earlier visits, country etc... 
add some kind of if URI == XX meta no index instead?

Comment: @Iesus Sonesson - OK, I will try this one and see if it will fix the issue. Thank you